# object_id function is not working T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, objectid

I have created a function named 'fname'.

```
 /*
create function fname(@ss int)
returns int
with schemabinding
as
begin 
return @ss
end
*/

object_id('fname')
```

Now I want to get its id using object_id function by specifying its name. SQL Server gives an error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
>   Incorrect syntax near 'fname'.

Can anyone point what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A function is NOT a statement. Just add "select" to the beginning here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to use the function under the SELECT statement**

```
select object_id('fname')
```

I tried it and succeeded

```
create function fname(@ss int)
returns int
with schemabinding
as
begin 
return @ss
end

go
select  object_id('fname')
```